# GTK - Unable to set button size smaller

Tags: c, user-interface, gtk, padding

I'm looking to set the size of a button within a box and row in a listbox to just be the size of a single character. I would like the button to be a small remove button, which is just a small square big enough to hold a single 'X' character.

I'm having trouble getting the button to go any smaller than this:

[image]

This is my current code:

```
    GtkWidget *row1;
    GtkWidget *box1;
    GtkWidget *label1;
    GtkWidget *remBox1;
    GtkWidget *remBtn1;
    GtkWidget *remBtnLbl1;

    remBtnLbl1 = gtk_label_new("X");
    gtk_widget_set_name(remBtnLbl1,"remBtnLabels");
    row1 = gtk_list_box_row_new();
    box1 = gtk_box_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL, 100);
    label1 = gtk_label_new("Test");
    remBox1 = gtk_button_box_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL);
    remBtn1 = gtk_button_new();

    gtk_widget_set_margin_start(remBtnLbl1, 0);
    gtk_widget_set_margin_end(remBtnLbl1, 0);

    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(remBtn1), remBtnLbl1);

    gtk_widget_set_name(remBtn1, "remButtons");
    gtk_widget_set_size_request(remBox1, 1, -1);
    gtk_widget_set_size_request(remBtn1, 1, 5);

    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(remBox1), remBtn1, FALSE, FALSE, 0);
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(box1), label1, TRUE, TRUE, 0);
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(box1), remBox1, FALSE, FALSE, 0);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(row1), box1);
    gtk_list_box_insert(GTK_LIST_BOX(hashListBox), row1, -1);
```

Stylesheet.css:

```
#remBtnLabels {
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
}
```

I've been trying all sorts of things to try and get the button smaller, and have been having no luck.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your specific example, just set the horizontal alignment of button:

```
gtk_widget_set_halign(remBtn1, GTK_ALIGN_END);
```